# More efficient/clean piece of javascript code requested

Tags: javascript

```
this.action = function(value){
        var deleted=false;
        for (var row in binaryObj) {
            if(value == 3){
                for(var i = 0 ; i < binaryObj[row].length; i++){
                    binaryObj[row].sort();
                    if(binaryObj[row][i]+binaryObj[row][i+1] === value) {                       
                        for(var j = 0; j < value; j++){
                            gameField.playField[row].pop(1);
                        }
                        deleted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                    for(var i = 0 ; i < binaryObj[row].length; i++){                
                            if(binaryObj[row][i] === value) {
                                for(var j = 0; j < value; j++){
                                    gameField.playField[row].pop(1);
                                }
                                deleted = true;
                                break;
                            }

                        if(deleted==true){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            if(deleted==true){
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

As you can see, I am using a boolean to check whether an item has been deleted, so I can break out of all loops. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Why not just return from the function if there's nothing else you need to do?

Comment: Is this indentation weirdness a result of a copy-paste, or is this how your code actually looks?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is fix your indentation - is it it is a little nonsensical.

Then, recognize that whenever you set `deleted` to `true`, you're done with the function.  Instead of all of the extra stuff, just `return` from the function.

Also, in both branches you have the same behavior, where you seem to be clearing the `gameField`.  You can consolidate that into a function.

```
this.action = function(value) {
    var deleted = false;
    for (var row in binaryObj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < binaryObj[row].length; ++i) {
            if (value == 3) {
                binaryObj[row].sort();
                cleanField(row, value);
                return;
            } else if (binaryObj[row][i] == value) {
                cleanField(row, value);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

function cleanField(row, limit) {
    for (var j = 0; j < limit; ++j) {
        gameField.playField[row].pop(1);
    }
}
```